# Derivation of gravitational potential for Einasto model

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, galaxy-rotation-curve

I'm following this paper to understand how the gravitational potential is derived for the Einasto model: https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2012/04/aa18543-11/aa18543-11.html.
I got stuck with understanding between equation (18) and (19). Could you please provide some hints how the equation $\Psi(r)=\int_0^\infty \frac{M(r\prime)dr\prime}{r\prime^2}$ (18) can be integrated to get equation $\Psi(r)=\frac{GM}{h}s^{-1}[1-\frac{\Gamma(3n,s^{1/n})}{\Gamma(3n)}+\frac{s\Gamma(2n,s^{1/n})}{\Gamma(3n)}]$ (19), considering also equations $s=\frac{(d_n)^{1/n}r}{r_s}$ (10) and $M(r) = M[1-\frac{\Gamma(3n,s^{1/n})}{\Gamma(3n)}]$ (13).

Paper preprint available on Arxiv at [Analytical properties of Einasto dark matter haloes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5242)

Comment: Hello! Please include all relevant parts from external sources in your question so it remains understandable in case the link should break. For formulae, one can use MathJax (LaTeX) typesetting, see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you want to perform integrals of the [Einasto profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einasto_profile)

$\rho = \rho_{0} \exp{(-Ar^{\alpha})}$

of the form

$\int \rho r^{\beta}dr$ (as you can see in eq. 17)

To accomplish this, you usually want to make use of the Gamma function: (eq. 14)

$ \Gamma(\alpha,x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}dt$

which helps you to perform integrals of an exponential times the integration variable to some power. This is why the Gamma function appears in eq. 19. To use this approach, it is actually easier to start from eq. 17 which is equivalent to eq. 18 and leads to eq. 19.

Comment: Thank you Alwin! I was able to get eq.19 based on your hints

Comment: My pleasure Andrei, please accept the answer if you feel it is appropriate :)